# Excel 2013: I need to go to last row in a table, go up 48 rows, then sum every 12th row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know that I can use an offset/counta to get to the bottom, then go up a certain amount of rows. But if I use this with a sum, for example:

=SUM(OFFSET(M1,COUNTA(M:M)-47,0,12))

I will get a sum of 12 consecutive rows. I need every 12th row. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Your formula is getting a group of cells 12 rows high.  Change the 12 in your formula to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can modify the following for your circumstance of starting 48 rows from the bottom...

If your data starts in A1, then, in B1, try this (and copy it all the way down):

=IF(MOD(ROW($A1),12)=0,SUM(INDIRECT("A"&ROW($A1)-12+1&":A"&ROW($A1))),"")

Your sum should appear on every 12th row, like shown below.  If you want to change it to some other interval, just change the 12 in the formula (highlighted red in 2 places below)
:

[image]

Comment: I don't think I explained properly. I want to start at the bottom of my column, go up 47 rows, then total every 12th cell to the bottom of the columm. My end result, using your example and starting at the bottom, row 49, should start 47 rows up at row A2 and would add together the values in cells A2, A14, A26, and A38 (every 12th row).